# doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: host+"/fgerp-ms-2.0.0/oauth/token?"+"grant_type="+"password&username=fgapiuser&password=fgapiuser",
                async: true,
               crossDomain: true,
          beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        /* Authorization header */
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("fgapiservice" + ":" + "fg@1234$"));
        
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,OPTIONS");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
               xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Length, X-JSON");
             xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization")
           xhr.withCredentials = true;
             },
        
                success: function (result) {
                result.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', '*');
                alert("in success"+result.access_token);
                accesstoken=result.access_token;
                });
```

i am calling it in my local
please let me know the solution

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers are **response** headers. It would be pointless if your JavaScript could grant **itself** permission to access data on someone else's server.

Comment: Please do some research before asking an already-answered-question.

Comment: Hello but i am getting the cors error what can i do for it

Comment: i have tried all the methods that mentioned but none worked for me